# SSH with Paramiko : failing to read data 

Tags: python, ssh, io, paramiko, buffered

Below is my driver information where I need to pull the data(Firmware Version) using ssh script as show below.

```
ncmdvstk:~ $ ssh admin@153.88.127.21
Password:

MSM760 V. 5.3.6.18-01-9124
(C) 2010 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, L.P.

CLI> enable
CLI# show system info
 [CPU info]   [Mem in  fo]
Firmware Version: 5.3.6.18-01-9124         Load 1min:       0.34   Total RAM:  9
```

This is the program I am using to read all the data first in "data" variable, so that later i can split n get info i need but where as no data it's printing in print data:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('153.88.127.21', username='admin',password='catfish')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("enable")
stdin.write('show system info \n')
data = stdout.read() 
print data
```

Please correct me on getting the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a call to `stdin.flush()` after the `stdin.write()` otherwise the input you're sending will stay buffered.